# Rendering videos slower

Tags: video, encoding

I've got some movies which should be used for tutorial aspects. Problem: the shown stuff is too fast, I need to slow down the movies.

Does anyone know a tool / programm which can do this? The movies are in `mp4` format.

Comment: Ok I solved my problem with a little workaround: First I save my video as avi after that I change the framerate (to get the video slower you must decrease the frame rate). As final step I convert my avi to mp4 (h.264). And I'm done. Maybe there is a smarter way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime 7 Pro is able to scale a track (audio or video) to the length of another track.

Answer (score 0):

Media player classic can speed up or down a movie using CTRL + up/down arrow. It's included with some codec packs like CCCP. Or you can get it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpc-hc/files/ .

EDIT: it only speeds up/down the playback, it doesn't save it in the video file (not sure if this is what you wanted). You can also go frame by frame using left/right arrows.

Comment: I want to edit the speed of the video file directly so that there is no user input required.